# Cheerio Get Image Src With No Class

Tags: jquery, node.js, cheerio

Trying to pull the img source with Cheerio, but the img doesn't have a class.  It looks like

```
<div class="container_c89a5 lazyLoadContainer_b1038">
<img height="80" src="https://stuff.com" srcset="https://stuff.com" width="80">
</div>
```

I've tried selecting the image source a couple different ways with no luck.

```
var $ = cheerio.load(html);
    $('div.item_54fdd').each(function(i, element) {
        var a = $(this);
        var title = a.find('.title_9ddaf').text(); //works great
        var image = a.find('div.container_c89a5').first('img').attr('src');  //no luck
        var image = a.find('div.container_c89a5 > img').attr('src');  //no luck
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have you tried using `find()`? 
This works for me:

```
a.find('.container_c89a5').find('img').attr('src');
```

Selecting first `img` tag via index using `eq(i)`

```
a.find('.container_c89a5').children('img').eq(0).attr('src');
```

Comment: No luck with either of those.  Now I'm thinking it's undefined because the images are lazy loaded, so there's actually nothing there before the jquery happens :/

Comment: Can you try to replicate your scenario in jsfiddle?

Comment: @gitterio can you please explain how's its working , its not works at all

Comment: `a.find('.container_c89a5').find('img')` is the same as `a.find('.container_c89a5 img')`

Answer (score 1):

The thing you have to do is to check the DOM with:

```
console.log(.container_c89a5 .lazyLoadContainer_b1038)
```

after that you see the DOM json format.
You can choose img by this kind of way:

```
console.log(.container_c89a5 .lazyLoadContainer_b1038).next()) or .children())
```

After that you will see the DOM and all the new thing and you can have access with a .data or .src, just check the DOM with console.log